# Compile C Python extension module on Solaris

Tags: python, c, gcc, solaris

It fails both with `cc`:

```
vagrant@sunos:/vagrant/psutil$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psutil._psutil_sunos' extension
/ws/on11update-tools/SUNWspro/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc -m32 -xO4 -xchip=pentium -xregs=no%frameptr -mt -KPIC -DPIC -xO5 -xtarget=opteron -xarch=sse2 -xcache=generic -m32 -xO4 -xchip=pentium -xregs=no%frameptr -mt -KPIC -DPIC -xO5 -xtarget=opteron -xarch=sse2 -xcache=generic -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=501 -DPSUTIL_SUNOS=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c psutil/_psutil_sunos.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-i86pc.32bit-2.7/psutil/_psutil_sunos.o
unable to execute /ws/on11update-tools/SUNWspro/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc: No such file or directory
error: command '/ws/on11update-tools/SUNWspro/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc' failed with exit status 1
vagrant@sunos:/vagrant/psutil$
```

...and `gcc`:

```
vagrant@sunos:/vagrant/psutil$ CC=gcc python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psutil._psutil_sunos' extension
gcc -m32 -xO4 -xchip=pentium -xregs=no%frameptr -mt -KPIC -DPIC -xO5 -xtarget=opteron -xarch=sse2 -xcache=generic -DNDEBUG -fPIC -DPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=501 -DPSUTIL_SUNOS=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c psutil/_psutil_sunos.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-i86pc.32bit-2.7/psutil/_psutil_sunos.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mt’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-KPIC’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
vagrant@sunos:/vagrant/psutil$
```

System is:

```
vagrant@sunos:/vagrant/psutil$ uname -a
SunOS sunos 5.11 11.2 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

Any advice?

Comment: Doesn't look like you have the Solaris compiler installed, and maybe not the correct gcc version..

Comment: The GCC version is ok, it just doesn't recognize the Sun Studio command line options.

Comment: Is "solaris compiler" some kind of installer I need to download from Sun's web site? I thought I had two compilers installed already: cc and gcc.

Comment: `/ws/on11update-tools/SUNWspro/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc` is not the normal path to the Solaris Studio cc compiler.   If you've already installed it, try using `CC=/usr/bin/cc` or whatever path you installed it under.  If you haven't installed it yet, download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/index.html .